# Hesitation on acceleration and no power when the AC is on and slight shake on idle

Tags: honda, maintenance, repair, hesitation

I have a honda jazz with an automatic transmission and im experiencing some hesitation when accelerating with the AC on, but with the AC off it runs so smooth that its like im riding a different car. And ive observed that when parked or in a stop with the engine on the car shakes/vibrates for like 2 seconds and it shakes quite often but for only 2 seconds then goes back to normal. And it also runs very rough when the car is shifted to drive with a cold engine, the rpm drops below 500 and hesitates bad with a weird engine sound but as the engine gets warm the roughness disappears along with the weird sound.

what causes all these? i can imagine it involves a lot of things but can you guys help me out?

Ive also observed that every time i let off the gas, the rate of which the speed reduces varies from time to time, it sometimes feels like downshifting in manual car as i left of the gas(that slight braking feel when u downshift), and sometimes its smooth. is it a normal car behavior?

Edit:
there are no codes and no check engine light

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Are there any codes? (Check engine light on?)

Comment: no codes, no check engine light

Answer (score 0):

Is this car new to you? Is it acting different than it used to? Is the difference in acceleration drastic? Lower HP cars will have noticeable performance difference between AC on or off. If it's drastic or acting differently with the AC on or off, it points to a problem with the AC compressor as it's not engaged when the ac is off.

The other issue with the rough idle could be any number of things, is this behavior with the AC on? If not it could still be the AC compressor if the bearings in the pulley are shot. Could also be unrelated, a lot of things under the hood can cause a rough idle. A worn bearing on a pulley could be the culprit. Side note, I had a car with a vacuum leak that would be very rough at idle but otherwise was smooth.

I would address the AC issue and see if you still have the rough idle problems, too many variables at this point.